# How to fix a .sb3 file that does not load anymore?

Tags: file, corruption, mit-scratch

I've been working on this little scratch project for a while now and today, i tried loading the file in turbowarp and this error message showed up:

`Could not load project: {"validationError":"Could not parse as a valid SB2 or SB3 project.","sb3Errors":\[{"keyword":"required","dataPath":".targets\[69\].costumes\[6\]","schemaPath":"#/required","params":{"missingProperty":"assetId"},"message":"should have required property 'assetId'"}\],"sb2Errors":\[{"keyword":"required","dataPath":"","schemaPath":"#/required","params":{"missingProperty":"objName"},"message":"should have required property 'objName'"}\]}`

Is there a way to fix this? If not, does anybody know what could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you load that same project in Scratch (without TurboWarp)? The first error says that one of your costumes is missing required property `"assetId"`.

The scratch project is a zip file containing all assets and a JSON file of the project itself. The `costume` section looks like this:

```
        "costumes": [
            {
                "name": "Ball-a",
                "bitmapResolution": 1,
                "dataFormat": "svg",
                "assetId": "3c6241985b581284ec191f9d1deffde8",
                "md5ext": "3c6241985b581284ec191f9d1deffde8.svg",
                "rotationCenterX": 22,
                "rotationCenterY": 22
            }
        ],
```

Can you check if there is that `"assetId"` in it?