# After saving a project in Turbowarp, I tried to load it and got a message saying "could not load project"

Tags: corruption, corrupt, mit-scratch

This is the second time this has happened to me, and the last time it fixed itself, but now it stopped working. I got this message: Could not load project: {"validationError":"Could not parse as a valid SB2 or SB3 project.","sb3Errors":[{"keyword":"required","dataPath":".targets[0].sounds[0]","schemaPath":"#/required","params":{"missingProperty":"assetId"},"message":"should have required property 'assetId'"}],"sb2Errors":[{"keyword":"required","dataPath":"","schemaPath":"#/required","params":{"missingProperty":"objName"},"message":"should have required property 'objName'"}]}

I don't know what it means, but it looks like it's assetId in sounds? Also, the "load restore point" also gives me the same message.

I have tried copying the file and reloading it, I've tried loading a restore point, and I've tried shutting down and restarting my computer. Nothing has worked. Here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13I8f7gMoYi3b2V5KwxZjz7U1-eabZfbM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems you are not the first to have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552807/how-to-fix-a-sb3-file-that-does-not-load-anymore

Answer (score 1):

these could be the following reasons of one or more of these:

- excessive and/or messy cloud data
- huge lists with 50000-to the max of 200000
- too many variables with the value 1000000000000000000 or higher
- complex custom blocks
- sprites are too detailed and are in large quantities
- file is simply too big (100+ MB)
- poor internet connection

Be sure you are not loading projects with heavy cloud content. the more cloud data transfer the project contains, the more problems your likely to face.

huge lists/variables will cause excessive processing and retrieval time that could trigger the unresponsive timer in the browser and cause the page to crash.

custom blocks are a great way to make complex code simpler, but if you make them too long Ex: (find position of everything (X: ) (y: ) (xy: ) (yx: ) (xx: ) (yy: ) (xyxy: ) (yxyx: ) (yxz: ) (yxzyxz: ) (Dir: ) (dis: ) (prob: ) (H: ) (W: ) (dim: ) (weight: ) (volocity: ) ) [that is just an example not something you would use] then you can make it harder for the custom configuration to process it a timely manner and would help cause it to crash (though it probably wouldn't on its own)

large sprites with excessive photographic detail is one of the most glitchy and file space consuming ways to slow projects and could make it difficult to lead to the turbo warp editor

make sure the file is less than 100 MG in size or it will not except it.

and lastly, if you have a poor internet connection the sight runs slow and could make file importing difficult. but it should be possible to load the project if the editor was loaded on good internet connection prior to poor or lost connection.

hope this helps! ask me if you have any more questions!